# Angular2 - PrimeNG calendar timeOnly unconfigured

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-calendar

After PrimeNG evolves to version "^1.0.0-rc.3", the following problem appears with the calendar :

`<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="date7" [timeOnly]="true"></p-calendar>`

[image: primeng-calendar]

I've tried everything and I can not change.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to update your primeng version today 2.0 RC1 is released maybe it solves your problem.